# Allocating memory for process in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management

Dear all, I am using Redhat linux ,How to set maximum memory for particular process. For eg i have to allocate maximum memory usage to eclipse alone .Is it possible to allocate like this.Give me some solutions.

Comment: I want to set that memory as permanent for particular process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control memory usage; you can only control virtual memory size, not the amount of actual memory used, as that is extremely complicated (perhaps impossible) to know for a single process on an operating system which supports virtual memory.

Not all memory used appears in the process's virtual address space at a given instant, for example kernel usage, and disc caching. A process can change which pages it has mapped in as often as it likes (e.g. via mmap() ). Some of a process's address space is also mapped in, but not actually used, or is shared with one or more other processes. This makes measuring per-process memory usage a fairly unachievable goal in practice.

And putting a cap on the VM size is not a good idea either, as that will result in the process being killed if it attempts to use more.

The right way of doing this in this case (for a Java process) is to set the heap maximum size (via various well-documented JVM startup options). However, experience suggests that you should not set it less than 1Gb.

Comment: Ya Mark you are right i couldn't found any solution for this task.I tried Andre's solution.But that controls the virtual memory only.So i opt your last point to increase the heap memory size (for java).Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
ulimit -v 102400
eclipse
```

...gives eclipse 100MiB of memory.

Comment: Thanks, After giving this command in prompt it will allocate 100MB to eclipse. Then how to find this allocated memory for eclipse.